# Tree PATH recursive problem in SQL , I think it recursive

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, select, recursive-query

This table have two columns `DepartmentId` and `Parent_DepartmentId`. I need to generate the `PATH` column with out using DDL commands. I know that its recursion, but I dont understand recursion. 
What is the answer to this? 
Thanks

Comment: Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question. It involves a little more effort than "What is the answer to this?".

Answer (score 0):

You could typically use a recursive query for this. Assuming that a `parent_department_id` of  `-1` indicates the root of the tree:

```
with cte as (
    select department_id, parent_department_id, cast(department_id as varchar(max)) path
    from mytable
    where parent_department_id = -1
    union all
    select 
        t.department_id,
        t.parent_department_id,
        path + '.' + cast(t.department_id as varchar(max))
    from mytable t
    inner join cte c on c.department_id = t.parent_department_id
)
select * from cte
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a1f22840c0f1ce5937259c3808e90697)**:

```
department_id | parent_department_id | path     
------------: | -------------------: | :--------
            0 |                   -1 | 0        
            1 |                    0 | 0.1      
            2 |                    1 | 0.1.2    
            3 |                    1 | 0.1.3    
            4 |                    0 | 0.4      
            5 |                    2 | 0.1.2.5  
            6 |                    5 | 0.1.2.5.6
            7 |                    1 | 0.1.7
```

Comment: Thank you very much you really help me a lot

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use `hierachyid` data type

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([DepartmentId] int,[Parent_DepartmentId] int)  
Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 (0,-1)
,(1,0)
,(2,1)
,(3,1)
,(4,0)
,(5,2)
,(6,5)
,(7,1)


;with cteP as (
      Select DepartmentId
            ,Parent_DepartmentId 
            ,HierID = convert(hierarchyid,concat('/',DepartmentId,'/'))
      From   @YourTable 
      Where  Parent_DepartmentId =-1
      Union  All
      Select DepartmentId  = r.DepartmentId
            ,Parent_DepartmentId  = r.Parent_DepartmentId 
            ,HierID = convert(hierarchyid,concat(p.HierID.ToString(),r.DepartmentId,'/'))
      From   @YourTable r
      Join   cteP p on r.Parent_DepartmentId  = p.DepartmentId)
Select Lvl   = HierID.GetLevel()
      ,DepartmentId
      ,Parent_DepartmentId
      ,Path = HierID.ToString()
 From cteP A
 Order By A.HierID
```

**Returns**

[image]